# How to Angular 6/7 project as dynamic plugin into another Angular 6/7 project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Building new platform in Angular 7 but having 6 to 8 existing project and planning inject all existing Angular projects dynamically into base project as a plugin. Please share your thoughts and feasibility to achieve this approach.

Example:

A(Base project)
 |__ A1(Existing Angular 6 project)
 |__ A2(Existing Angular 6 project)

Using rollup.js able to achieve using System.js. But looking forward any alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here would be to make make your applications you want to inject Angular libraries. There are a number of tutorials on how to do that, e.g. https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11.

The basic steps per library are:

- `ng g library [name of your library]`,
- move all functionality from the given app into that library,
- export all shared services/components in the library's `Module`,
- publish or link the library as a NPM package,
- import it in your new application by referencing it in the `imports` section of your `AppModule`.